# How to update progress bar of an element div?

Tags: jquery

Tell me please it is necessary that the progress bar is updated when scrolling, switching to another div .item element in a common container .container

here is an example [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/pichugin/pen/eYpLzRj)

```
$(function() {
   $(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
      let o = $(window).scrollTop() / ($('.item').height() - $(window).height());
      console.log(o)
      $(".progress-bar").css({
         "width": (100 * o | 0) + "%"
      })
      $('progress')[0].value = o;
   })
})
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? Do you want the progressbar to reset to 0 when you reach another div with a class of item?

Comment: yes that's what I want